# PHP Foreach query only displays final result for slideshow?

Tags: php, html, ffmpeg

Using a query I pull the most liked video's on a localhosted stream webpage, and use FFMPEG to create a thumbnail if one isnt already existing and the video length.

The query succesfully pulls the 4 most liked video's and displays them in a carousel. FFMPEG succesfully creates each thumbnail, and gets the length of each video.

Somewhere, for whatever reason I cant figure out, only the final slide in the carousel displays the thumbnail as its background.

Sorry if my code is messy, I'm learning how to better optimize.

```
<?php
                $sql = "use info";
                $pdo->exec($sql);
                $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `files` ORDER BY `like` DESC LIMIT 4");
                $filelist = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    $h = 0;
                  foreach ($filelist as $row) {
                        if ($h < 25){
                        $h++;
                
                            $name = $row['name'];
                            $location = $row['location'];
                            $type = $row['type'];
                            $uploadby = $row['uploadby'];
                            $like = $row['like'];
                            $id = $row['fileid'];
                            $cat1 = $row['Cat1'];
                            $cat2 = $row['Cat2'];
            
                $ffmpeg = 'F:\\xampp\ffmpeg.exe';  
                $location = str_replace("/","\\", $location);
                $video = 'F:\xampp\htdocs\\'. $location;  
                $bigloc = "F:\\xampp\htdocs\\thumb\big";
                $smallloc = "F:\\xampp\htdocs\\thumb\small";
                $image = $bigloc . "\\" . $name . ".jpg"; 
                $image2 = $smallloc . "\\" . $name. ".jpg"; 
                            
                if (file_exists($image) and (file_exists($image2))) {
                    
                } else {
                echo $image . " does not exist";
                $cmd="$ffmpeg -ss 00:25:00 -i ". "\"" . $video . "\"". " -s 1920x540 -vframes 1 ". "\"" .$image. "\"" . " -report";  
                $cmd2="$ffmpeg -ss 00:25:00 -i ". "\"" . $video . "\""." -s 270x370 -vframes 1 ". "\"" .$image2. "\"";
                echo "<br>". $cmd . "<br>".$cmd2."<br>";
                exec($cmd);
                exec($cmd2);
                }
                
                $file = "\"". $video. "\"";
                $result = shell_exec('ffmpeg -i ' . escapeshellcmd($file) . ' 2>&1');
                preg_match('/(?<=Duration: )(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\.\d{2}/', $result, $match);
                $time = $match[1];
                $image = "thumb/big/" . $name . ".jpg"; 
                $image2 = "thumb/small/" . $name. ".jpg";

            ?>

            <div class="single-hero-slider-wrap single-animation-wrap slider-height-hm4 bg-image-hm4 slider-bg-color-black d-flex align-items-center slider-bg-position-1 bg-black" style="<?php echo 'background-image:url('. $image.');';?>">
                <div class="slider-content-hm4 slider-animated">
                    <h1 class="title animated"><?php echo $name;?></h1>
                    <div class="sub-title-time-wrap">
                        <span class="sub-title animated"><?php if ($cat2 != ""){ echo $cat1 .", ". $cat2; }else{ echo $cat1;}?></span>
                        <span class="time animated"><?php echo $time;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slider-button">
                        <a href="movie-details.html" class="btn-style-hm4 animated">Watch Now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php    
                        }
                  }              
            ?>
```

When inspecting the source code on my web browser;
"`style="<?php echo 'background-image:url('. $image.');';?>"`", this will only appear on the final slide. The first 3 slides wont have "background-image" at all.

I feel as though I'm making a silly mistake and just cant see it.

*EDIT*
I should note, the "$name" and "$time" for each displays properly, its just the background-image that does not.

*EDIT 2*
Here is the source code:

```
<div class="single-hero-slider-wrap single-animation-wrap slider-height-hm4 bg-image-hm4 slider-bg-color-black d-flex align-items-center slider-bg-position-1 bg-black" style="background-image: url('thumb/big/Alita Battle Angel.png');">
```

The "background-image" shows in source, but during inspect element it does not. No errors populate either.

Comment: I can’t tell, is the thumbnail creation through FFMpeg working, and you are just having problems displaying the images?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes, FFMpeg creates the thumbnail correctly. somewhere in the translation from PHP to html the background-image is lost. The styling doesnt even display in the source code.

Comment: Instead of inspecting, try viewing the source to see what is in there. The former can hide bugs because it is an interpretation of the latter. Also, instead of writing a `div`, start with just `var_dumps with your variables to see what’s there

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yep, viewing source instead of inspect object results in me seeing that background-image exists, but it just not being displayed... What could cause this?

Comment: Can you post the source?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Updated post to include Source under *EDIT 2*. I'm even more confused now.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Rookie move, cant believe this; There are spaces in the file name. I should have noticed this right away. Is there a way to display the image even with spaces?

Answer (score 0):

So, little bit (huge bit) of a rookie move. I had FFMpeg creating thumbnails in JPG format... but in the HTML I was recalling the file as a PNG. My supposed answer in the comments was wrong, it had nothing to do with spaces, and everything to do with me not paying attention. Thanks @ChrisHaas.